# read configuration settings from validation.yml

Tags: php, symfony

I want to read any parameter settings since file "validation.yml", but when trying to do is not interpreted.

Example:

In PHP would get the parameter "locale" as follows:

```
$locate = $this->container->getParameter('locale');
```

When I try to do the same in the file "validation.yml"

```
# validation.yml
App\LoginBundle\Validations\Login:
    properties:
        field:
            - NotBlank:
                message: "%locale%"
```

The visible result is literally:  **%locale%**

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently **not possible** to include container-parameters in validation messages directly inside a validation-mapping file.

This is due to the fact that the validation class-metadata has **no relation** to the container-configuration.

Until symfony `2.1` container-parameters couldn't be used in route-definitions either.

```
The ability to use parameters in your routes was added in Symfony 2.1.
```

(see: [How to use Service Container parameters in your routes](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/routing/service_container_parameters.html))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try without quotes?

```
# validation.yml
App\LoginBundle\Validations\Login:
    properties:
        field:
            - NotBlank:
                message: %locale%
```

Comment: Yes, I try, the result is the same

Comment: What about `%_locale%` or `_locale`?

Comment: I tried: %locale%, "%locale%", %_locale%, "%_locale%", locale, _locale, the result is the same.

Comment: So try to use pattern for example `__locale__` in `validation.yml` file, and then replace this pattern in controller or twig by a real `locale` variable

Comment: This method works perfect, but I wanted to find a direct way.

Comment: I think there is no any other way